# Does Inheritance and Aggregation class relationships related to the ownership?

Tags: oop, relationship

I know that composition implements complete ownership while association does not involve ownership. What about Inheritance and Aggregation?

Comment: Here is a Wikipedia link which might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance: one thing is also another type of thing and inherits all of the attributes of that other type of thing.  (Example: a student is also a person.)

Aggregation: one thing currently owns another thing, but the other thing doesn't require the owner to exist.  (This is in contrast to composition, where one thing owns another thing, which requires the owner to exist.)

For example, a table has a surface on which to place things -- the surface cannot exist apart from the table (and have the table still be a table).  The table is composed from (among other things) a surface.

But a table can have many plates on it -- the table aggregates the plates.  The plates can still exist apart from the table (you can put them in the cupboard).

Comment: So, from these 4 relationships (Inheritance, Aggregation, Composition, Association) only Composition related to the ownership?

Comment: @Dr_Cringe Aggregation can be owning, but the owned object is not an inseparable part of its owning object.